# React-scripts test: no traceback on exception

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jestjs, react-scripts

I remake browser version of [TacticToy game](https://www.aivanf.com/tactictoy) with React, and during unit-tests writing I've got a problem: there is no full traceback of a custom exception, only test function is highlighted:

[image: TacticToy tests: missing error traceback]

In the `package.json` file's `scripts` section I have `"test": "react-scripts test"`, it runs Jest under the hood. I tried to run Jest without React-scripts, but this leads to lots of errors, seems like React adds some important config... So, what and how should I adjust to receive tracebacks of exceptions thrown during the tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the ESLint, I found the problem source: the code threw exceptions as plain strings, and when I replace it with `throw new Error("text")` I receive the stack trace `:)`

The solution is pretty simple (and it doesn't relate to React nor Jest), strange that I've googled no explanation... Here is a moral: always use a linter!